# Powershell: Delete All Intermediate Folders in a Hierarchy

Tags: powershell

I have something like the following (an export from a document management system).

```
C:\Export\{GUID}\Files\{GUID}\0\0-999\2\L\L\file1.txt
C:\Export\{GUID}\Files\{GUID}\0\0-999\3\L\L\file1.txt
C:\Export\{GUID}\Files\{GUID}\0\0-999\4\L\L\MultiFileName\file1.txt
C:\Export\{GUID}\Files\{GUID}\0\0-999\5\L\L\file2.txt
etc...
```

What I would like to do is to move everything to `C:\Export` so it would look like this

```
C:\Export\file1.txt
C:\Export\file1-{something}.txt
C:\Export\MultiFileName\file1.txt
C:\Export\file2.txt
etc...
```

The `\{GUID}\Files\{GUID}\0` and `\L\L\` parts are static, but the `\0-999\2\` can be anything between `\0-999\2\` and `\1000-1999\1999\`

I'm at a complete loss as to where to start with this, no one on the whole Internet seems to have run into a problem where they want to preserve the last folder in the hierarchy (which would solve a large part of the problem).

EDIT: After posting this it became apparent that this could be boiled down a bit, I'm now dealing with the following:

```
C:\Export\2\L\L\file1.txt
C:\Export\3\L\L\file1.txt
C:\Export\4\L\L\MultiFileName\file1.txt
C:\Export\5\L\L\file2.txt
...
C:\Export\1999\L\L\file1999.txt
```

So, the issue is, how do I remove all intermediate folders that are either named `L` or a number between 0 and 1999? Like this:

```
C:\Export\file1.txt
C:\Export\file1-1.txt
C:\Export\MultiFileName\file1.txt
C:\Export\file2.txt
...
C:\Export\file1999.txt
```

Comment: How will name collisions be handled?

Comment: It doesn't really matter how, in case of a collision a GUID or something could be appended. I saw some code in another question that handled that part, not too sure if I can implement it though. :)

Comment: Does the `EDIT` show the input file list or what you want as the output file list?

Comment: The EDIT shows the input, I'll add the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the DEL line until you are happy with results.  The code only keeps one copy of each file.  You have duplicate filenames

```
$folder = 'c:\Export'

foreach($subfolder in $folder)
{
   $files = Get-ChildItem $Folder -File -Recurse
   foreach($file in $files)
   {
       copy $file.Fullname $subfolder\$file.Name
   }
   Get-ChildItem $folder -Directory | foreach {del /Q $_.Fullname}
}
```

Comment: `del` is an alias of `Remove-Item` so `/Q` will clearly fail. In addition trying to use the actual `del` command in powershell is nonsense.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon : Did you try it?  It is working on my machine.  Del is a cmd.exe method.

Comment: If it works for you is because you've removed the alias for `del -> Remove-Item` probably.